# Differential of a trigonometric function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

If $x\sin \left( {\alpha  + y} \right) = \sin y$ and $y' = \frac{m}{{{x^2} + 2nx + 1}}$ , then find the value of $m^2+n^2$ .{where $y' = \frac{{dy}}{{dx}}$}

My approach is as follow

$x\cos \left( {\alpha  + y} \right)y' + \sin \left( {\alpha  + y} \right) = y'\cos y \Rightarrow y'\left( {x\cos \left( {\alpha  + y} \right) - \cos y} \right) =  - \sin \left( {\alpha  + y} \right)$

$\Rightarrow y' = \frac{{ - \sin \left( {\alpha  + y} \right)}}{{\left( {x\cos \left( {\alpha  + y} \right) - \cos y} \right)}}$

How will corelate the above equation with $y' = \frac{m}{{{x^2} + 2nx + 1}}$

[image]

Comment: Where is this question from ?

Comment: It is from an old paper of a coach , let me modify the question

Comment: @jimjim I copied the question at the bottom of my question, this seem to be a tough question

Comment: Is there a physics relevance?

Comment: No this is maths related questions

Answer (score 1):

> $x\sin \left( {\alpha  + y} \right) = \sin y$ and $\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{m}{{{x^2} + 2nx + 1}}$. Find (m,n).

We have ;

$$x\sin \left( {\alpha  + y} \right) = \sin y$$

Using $\sin(\alpha+y)=\sin(\alpha)\cos(y)+\cos(\alpha)\sin(y)$,

$$x\sin(\alpha)\cos(y)+x\cos(\alpha)\sin(y) = \sin y$$

divide by $\cos(y)$ on either sides;

$$x\sin(\alpha)+x\cos(\alpha)\tan(y) = \tan(y)$$

$$x\sin(\alpha)=tan(y)\left[1-x\cos(\alpha)\right]$$

$$\frac{x\sin(\alpha)}{\left[1-x\cos(\alpha)\right]}=tan(y)$$

$$arctan\left[\frac{x\sin(\alpha)}{1-x\cos(\alpha)}\right]=y$$

Differentiate with respect to $x$ on either sides and rearrange the terms, you'll get $(m,n)=(\sin(\alpha),-\cos(\alpha))$ and the final answer is $1$;